# Plotting station observations over US map in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, size, symbols

I have precipitation data and corresponding lat long information for US. I want to produce precipitation distribution map with symbol size indicating magnitude of event; such as smaller circle representing small magnitude of precipitation & larger circle indicating larger event, How can I do this in MATLAB, can anybody kindly help me in this regard..Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to code spatial distribution of precipitation. I want to make size & colour of the symbols say circle, based on magnitude of precipitation.